# Closure of a subset of R

Tags: general-topology

Munkeres defines closure of subset S of topological space X as

> Closure of set S is the intersection of all closed sets containing S

We denote closure of set S as cl(S).He then goes to prove following theorem:

> **Let X be a topological Space. Then** $ \mathtt {x \in cl(S)} \Leftarrow\Rightarrow \mathtt{Every\: Open\: set\:U\: in\: X\: containing\: x\: intersects\: S}$

Now he gives an example:

> **Let X be R,the set of 1 dimensional Real number. Let :**

$$\text{ S := {$\frac{1}{n}$ | n $\in Z_{+}$}  $Z_{+}$  is the  set of  all positive natural numbers}$$

**Now he tells cl(S)= {0} $\cup$ S.**

Now,I knew the concept of limit points and I can get this answer straightforward. However, I am unable to get answer using the defination and theorem above. My doubt is why only 0? Clearly an open ball about 0.5 satisfies defination. So,0.5 can also be in closure. I  am missing something here. Can anybody explain me the answer using the defination and theorem above?

Comment: 1/2 is in $S$, Maybe you didnt notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\frac12\in\overline S$ too. But $\frac12\in S$ and so this is consistent with Munkres' statement that $\overline S=S\cup\{0\}$. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Thanks. I was picturing it wrong way.